# Check page for any visible input forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

How to check if the DOM has any visible input forms, e.g. input field, select field, multitext field, etc. there is atleast one of those, I will need to run a certain code.  If all are hidden not atleast 1 is shown I will not show run the code.

```
if(ThereIsVisibleInputFields) {
    IWillRunThisCode();   
}
```

#### EDIT:

How about using this.

```
if($(":input:visible").length) {
    IWillRunThisCode();
}
```

Does `:input` selector selects all form elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The :visible selector is what you most likely need. You can use it as such-

```
if ($('input:visible, textarea:visible, select:visible').length > 0) {
    IWillRunThisCode();
}
```

You can check the jQuery api page for more info - [:visible Selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

Edit:
As pointed out by OP, the :input selector works equally well. Even better, it also selects buttons, which my original code didn't. So the selector should really be

```
if ($(':input:visible').length) {
    IWillRunThisCode();
}
```

Comment: I have a feeling that you don't need the `> 0` comparison, if the length is zero there won't *be* a length, so if there is a length it must be greater than zero. ...I do, however, have an imperfect understanding of JavaScript, though.

Comment: Ah, you're right.
If the `.length` property returns 0, it would obviously translate to false.

Comment: Hmmm yes, the :input selector would do the job. 
Learn something new everyday, as they say. I'll modify my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

```
function ThereIsVisibleInputFields(){
   var arr = new Array();
   arr = document.getElementsByTagName( "input" );
   for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++)
            {
                var tagName = document.getElementsByTagName( "*" ).item(i).nodeName;
                var tagObj = document.getElementsByTagName( "*" ).item(i);
                if(tagObj.style.visibility=="visible"||tagObj.style.display!="none")             
                     return true;
            }
   return false;
}
```

Similarly we can chek for other tags also(select,textarea etc)